# Moving from assembly to C

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, assembly

About four years ago i stumbled upon some electronics projects on the internet and ever since i fell in love with it. So I started at basic circuits then moved to analog circuits and spent very little there then logic circuits then microcontrollers.
Each step made the abstraction of the next one very clear and easy to 'de-abstract' if i can say.
So after spending some good time writing code in assembly and with the programs growing more complex and longer , the need for another transition for me from assembly to C has arisen.
The thing is that i didn't know any other programming language before learning assembly , and trying to learn embedded C from the current sources i have seems to be very hard for me as i can't 'de-abstract' the meaning of many of the language syntax.
So i would like that good sources for embedded C language learning be suggested which if possible links the explanations to lower language assembly not higher ones that i already can't 'de-abstract'.

Comment: Your question seems very broad, and answers would likely be based on opinion, so it is a poor fit for this community. Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions. Try to be more specific. What sources have you already found, and what are you finding difficult, or that they do not explain?

Comment: I almost made a rant as an answer. My answer: don't. To me assembly and C (however similar) are fundamentally different in thing: assembly is a set of instructions for the machine. C is a form of expression for **YOU** to describe your algorithm. A form of expression which is actually understandable for the machine. But that's just a personal opinion from a programmer.

Comment: Or take a look at LLVM's Intermediate Representation language, which is sort-of in between C and assembly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#LLVM_Intermediate_Representation

Comment: MostfaMahmoud - As gbulmer said, I agree this is not a good fit for EE.SE. However I'll try to help a little. I also moved from mainly assembler programming, to C programming, so I have experienced your problem. You said that you "can't 'de-abstract' the meaning of many of the language syntax" - stop trying to do that! Just accept that programming in C changes your mindset from handling every little detail (as with assembler), to describing what you want the machine to do. This is what @JanDorniak has said in a previous comment.

Comment: @JanDorniak That may be true for C programs targeted for "general use", but for embedded platforms when you have 2 kB of Flash and  CPU running at 32 kHz, you can gain a lot by understanding roughly what will happen on the machine level when writing things in C.

Comment: The thing people usually have trouble with in C is pointers. Coming from assembly, I'd be surprised if you have trouble with that. C is one of the most low-level languages out there.

Comment: @AdamHaun Agreed. Once you learn your compiler, it's essentially an optimizing macro assembler. :)

Comment: @pipe true that, but with the increasingly cheap cortex-m I don't really see any reason to go to weaker MCUs... but as already said I'm a programmer who only made a few simple (say water meter) projects on relatively powerful MCUs like cortex-m 0.

Comment: [This one](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/embed/toc1.htm) seems nice. Just don't spend too much time on the MCU-specific hardware stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get ahold of [K&R 2nd Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). It's a compact and dense book that covers what you need to know.

C and assembly are not *that* far apart, so you should make rapid progress.

Comment: I'd highly recommend K&R 2 as well. There are more recent books and larger books, but nothing more comprehensive or lucid.

Comment: I read about people who have difficulty learning from K&R 2, exactly because it is so dense. :-( And of course that book is stuck in a C89/90 era. So, although not aimed specifically at the assembler-to-C transition of the topic's OP, here is the canonical Stack Overflow topic on good C books, for readers who want to find alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: As someone who has worked full-time with embedded C programming for the past 15 years, I would strongly recommend to **avoid** this ancient book. It is terribly outdated, it is full of errors, it contains lots of bad programming practice. The concept of proper program design is completely absent throughout the book. I'm sick and tired of re-teaching proper, modern C to people who have been damaged by this book. Also note that the book's main focus are hosted systems, mainly Unix, and not embedded systems. Instead pick something modern, that covers C99 and C11.

Comment: @Lundin Well i think that advice is a bit late , as i have  already skimmed through half the book, however , before i begun reading it i decided to take it lightly because embedded C isnt its main focus as you have mentioned earlier, but i decided to read it first just to get a general idea, then i will read Embedded C Programming and the Atmel AVR, 2e Barnett ,cox and o'cull (without leaving exercises like i'm doing with K&R).
So i would really appreciate your advice and other book (instead of what i mentioned) recommendation and if i should leave K&R  at all without completing it.

Comment: @MostfaMahmoud I don't really know of any beginner-friendly C books, but you should try to find one which covers at least the C99 standard. Any yeah drop K&R asap. What you should do eventually is to look into MISRA-C:2012, which is a coding standard laying out rules that lead to safe, bug-free C programs. Very suitable for embedded systems in particular - it is becoming industry de facto standard. It is not easy reading for beginners though, but knowing about it is a merit that employers will look for.

Comment: @Lundin I'm really grateful for your advice, but i think it will be awhile till i dig into that as it is obvious that one needs to learn the language first before learning the guidelines of writing good code into it, however i think it will be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Microchip has several [free Compilers](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/compilers) that are paired with the free MPLABX IDE (Integrated Development Environment).  You can get a compiler for 8, 16 and 32-bit microcontrollers.

The difference between the free versions and the paid ones is the latter optimize the code, making the finished binary much smaller.  I've seen size of the binary shrink by half.

One feature of the IDE is that you can open a disassembly window which will show you your C program followed bu the code that it generated.  The following is from a PIC32 program (32-bit MIPS assembly):

[image]

Comment: Is there a free program with similar feature for AVR since i'm already accustomed to its instruction set and internal architecture, or should i learn PIC assembly (which i think it wont be hard as learning a specific assembly language for the first time).

Comment: @MostfaMahmoud What processor did you write assembly code for before?  I think that would be your best place to start.

Comment: AVR 8-bit microcontroller .

Comment: @MostfaMahmoud Sorry, I should have picked up that before when you said you were familiar with its instruction set.  I'm not familiar with the native AVR development tools, but it appears Atmel has a [free development suite](http://www.atmel.com/Microsite/atmel-studio/).